# Buttons inside ScrollView inside Gallery don’t respond to click

Tags: android, user-interface, touch, scrollview, android-gallery

I have a Gallery with ScrollViews as child items. Scroll view can contain text, images and button inside of the scroll area. I need to make sure that the touch events are handled correctly and as expected.

I’ve found solution a good here: [ScrollView inside Gallery, both scrolling independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286115/scrollview-inside-gallery-both-scrolling-independently)

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't help with buttons. Tapping on the button, sometimes, causes gallery control to scroll to the neighbor item.

How to prevent ScrollView and Gallery from scrolling then user is tapping on the button when button is inside of the scroll view and scroll view is item in the gallery control?

Can someone provide me with a solution of recognizing “click” gesture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had something like this once - I fixed it by adding an onClick in the XML:

```
<button android:onClick="handleClick" ... />
```

then in your code:

```
public void handleClick(View view) {
    // get the position of the clicked item in the list
    int position = getListView().getPositionForView(view);
    // do something with the item
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working. However, tapping on the button sometimes causes gallery control to scroll to the neighbor item. How to prevent ScrollView and Gallery from scrolling then user is tapping on the button?