# Custom Gallery: ScrollView inside Gallery: Selected Item has a overlaying color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I'm using the custom gallery in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286115/scrollview-inside-gallery-both-scrolling-independently). But when I select a item by **setSelection()** method the selected item has a white overlay. Is there any way to prevent it?